# Image Hot link Protection not Working with Latest Wordpress 4.4.2

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, hotlinking, google-image-search

I am facing a issue in **Hotlink Protection**.

I am using Wordpress 4.4.2, for image hot link protection I'm using Wordpress plugin name called WP-PICShield. It's worked well till Wordpress version 3.8.13, after I updated to latest version (4.4.2) its Not Working Well.

If a user clicks view image from Google Image Search, it's not redirected to attachment page/post page, instead of redirecting to attachment page, its redirecting to mysite.com/Image-not-found/ Page.

**(For example :)**

If I click it --- >  mysite.com/uploads/carwallpaper.jpg
it redirects to ---> mysite.com/Image-not-found/
But it's worked well until wordpress 3.8.13.

I Want to redirect it to --> mysite.com/PostName/ (or) mysite.com/attachmentpage

**I have 2 Sites, with same theme and plugins.**
But one site runs with wordpress 4.4.2  (hotlink Not Working)
another one site runs with wordpress 3.8.13 (hotlink Working)

I Have included a video Here -->([https://youtu.be/kbPWprXGqT4][1])

I Have included hotlink script & htaccess in Pastebin

byrev-wp-picshield.PHP---> http://pastebin.com/V5Wpwtbe

I can't able to add more than 2 Links, so I added below in comment

Comment: byrev-wp-image2url.php---> http://pastebin.com/aHV8qFEU

htaccess ----------------> http://pastebin.com/0uRBF0ZU

Comment: You should include the code in the question itself rather than in linked pastebin pages....

Comment: i am getting this msg while adding code.                                                               Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Answer (score 0):

Use php 5.4.45 version in your cPanel account.

Comment: Could you explain why he should use this exact php version please ?